# How to send an HTTP request at a specific time in Jmeter

Tags: java, request, jmeter, httprequest, http-request

I want to send an HTTP request every fifteen seconds, e.g.:

1. Send an HTTP request to the first user at T+0 (e.g. 10:00:00 AM)
2. Send the same HTTP request to user 2 at T+15sec (e.g. 10:00:15 AM)
3. Send this request to user 3 at T+30

Comment: Welcome to SO. So effectively you want a request sent in every 15 seconds? Why not use a constant timer? see: http://2min2code.com/articles/jmeter_intro/constant_timer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the test at a specific time, you can use JMeter `scheduler`. If the `Start Time` is future time, JMeter will wait & start the test @ that time.

If you need to add users for every 15 seconds, use the `Ramp Up` period.
For ex: total no of users are going to be 10, you need 1 user for every 15 seconds, ramp up period should be 150 seconds (15*10).

Comment: Thanks...Would you please also tell me how to send request for specific user...for eg.Consider there are multiple request to send  i.e user 1 will send Http Request1 and user2 will send http request5 and user3 will send http request4   ect....

Comment: you can accept this as the answer if it really clarifies your question or you can provide more info on the question. Regarding - sending request - i would suggest you to raise a separate question for detailed answer as it is not related to this question. short answer: it can be done using if controller or csv config.